# Apprehension in Feller's solution of a model of breakage of spores

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, mathematical-modeling

This one is a solved example from Feller.

> Spores of the Fungus are produced in chains of eight.The chain may
>   break into several parts into projectiles containing 1 to 8 pores.
>   Find the expected no. of doublets if all links have probability $p$ to
>   break.

If we assume $S$ to be the random variable which assumes the no. of doublets formed, then we need to evaluate $E[S]$. The maximum value $S$ can assume is $4$. However, Feller has expressed $S=S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4+S_5+S_6+S_7$ as there are $7$ different ways a doublet can be formed where $S_i \in \{0,1\}$. I'm unable to comprehend the equality of $S$ with $\sum S_i$ as they have different range with $S \in \{0,4\}$  and $\sum S_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

Can someone explain the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 2):

$\sum S_i$ has range $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ not $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. This is because the $S_i$ are dependent on each other. In particular,

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_1 = 1 &\implies& S_2 = 0 \\
S_2 = 1 &\implies& S_1 = S_3 = 0 \\
S_3 = 1 &\implies& S_2 = S_4 = 0 \\
S_4 = 1 &\implies& S_3 = S_5 = 0 \\
S_5 = 1 &\implies& S_4 = S_6 = 0 \\
S_6 = 1 &\implies& S_5 = S_7 = 0 \\
S_7 = 1 &\implies& S_6 = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

$\sum S_i$ attains its maximum of $4$ when $(S_1,\ldots,S_7) = (1,0,1,0,1,0,1)$.